# "handling_cart" being ignored by PayPal

Tags: paypal

I have a site that uses `handling_cart` to add a small P&P charge to all orders. The variable has been in use without problem for several years, but as of about two days ago PayPal has stopped including the amount in the total to pay.

Is this a bug, or a new feature?

Comment: For future reference it seems it was a PayPal error, which was fixed after a few days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug. You can change `handling_cart` to `shipping_1` as a temporary fix while you wait for PayPal to resolve the issue.

Comment: do you have any support for this? If PayPal is aware of it, do they have a status page or something where we can check?

Comment: I have not contacted PayPal directly myself, but have seen various forum posts from people who have received the same canned response that it's a known issue and is been worked on. I have used the above fix on a live site and postage is now applied correctly.

Comment: Same thing here, last couple of days handling_cart has stopped working. The shipping_1 fix didn't work either. Anyone has an update on this?

Answer (score 0):

We are seeing the same thing which started in the last 24 hours as far as I can see. It seems as if the cart upload handling_cart field is ignored now.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal developer tech support acknowledged that this was a problem and promised an update when it was officially fixed.

In the meantime, instead of passing in handling_cart, I added a fake product called "Shipping" onto the end of the order. So for example on a cart with three items in it and shipping of $18.50, I added a fourth product of quantity 1 called "Shipping":

```
item_name_4 = "Shipping"
quantity_4 = "1"
amount_4 = "18.50"
shipping_4 = "0.00"
shipping2_4 = "0.00"
```

I'm not wild about this workaround but at least we're collecting the right amount from the customers now.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed to be a problem in last 2 days. Paypal just made our orders from the last 2 days not have any shipping.

Answer (score 0):

the same issue here. having talked to paypal they are saying they are aware of the issue and suggested the following (temporary) workaround. might not be appropriate for  everybody, but seems to work for me

i just replaced/changed the variable `handling_cart` with `handling_1` maybe this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved as of now related to the "handling_cart" variable at the PayPal's end .

Comment: could you explain that in more detail? Does the issue appear to be fixed on PayPal's side or were you able to use one of the workarounds, if so, which one?

Answer (score 0):

In paypal.com they are written the variable name `handling_cart` as `handling_ cart`. It is a wrong usage they put an extra space after the underscore. It work for me when use this variable without space.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HF009YW